# Build WHERE clause for search conditions

Tags: c#, t-sql, extension-methods, oracle

Here is a set of classes that are used to build `where` clause for SQL Server and Oracle for different field types e.g. `text`, `numeric` and `date`.

```
public interface IConditionBuilder
{
    bool CanHandle(FilterAction filterAction);

    string BuildCondition(SearchCondition filterCondition);
}

public abstract class ConditionBuilder<TContext> : IConditionBuilder where TContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    public abstract string OperatorSymbol { get; }

    public string BuildCondition(SearchCondition searchCondition)
    {
        var conditionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var context = searchCondition.GetContext<TContext>();

        conditionBuilder.Append(context.FieldId);
        conditionBuilder.Append(OperatorSymbol);
        conditionBuilder.Append(GetValue(context));

        return conditionBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public abstract bool CanHandle(FilterAction filterAction);

    public abstract object GetValue(TContext context);

}

public class TextLikeConditionBuilder : ConditionBuilder<TextContext>
{
    public override string OperatorSymbol => " LIKE ";

    public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.TextLike;

    public override object GetValue(TextContext context)
    {
        if (context.Text == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return string.Concat("%", context.Text, "%");
    }
}

public class TextEqualsConditionBuilder : ConditionBuilder<TextContext>
{
    public override string OperatorSymbol => " = ";

    public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.TextEqual;

    public override object GetValue(TextContext context)
    {
        if (context.Text == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return "'" + context.Text + "'";
    }
}

public class NumericLessThanConditionBuilder : ConditionBuilder<NumericContext>
{
    public override string OperatorSymbol => " < ";

    public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.NumericLessThan;

    public override object GetValue(NumericContext context)
    {
        return context.Number;
    }
}

public class DateGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder : IConditionBuilder
{
    public const string GREATER_THAN = " > ";

    public const string LESS_THAN_EQUAL = " <= ";

    public string BuildCondition(SearchCondition filterCondition)
    {
        var conditionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var context = filterCondition.GetContext<DateContext>();

        conditionBuilder.Append(context.FieldId);
        conditionBuilder.Append(GREATER_THAN);
        conditionBuilder.Append("'" + context.FromDate + "'");
        conditionBuilder.Append(LESS_THAN_EQUAL);
        conditionBuilder.Append("'" + context.EndDate + "'");
        return conditionBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.DateGreaterThanLessThan;

}
```

I want to extend the functionality so that context.FieldId is sanitized before it is used to build the `condition` statement for e.g. these classes will build a statement like `Name = 'Aashish'`, I want the classes to build statement as `[Name] = 'Aashish'`. These classes are consumed by other developers so I don't want to break the functionality for consumers as a result of the changes I will make, basically adhere to Open-Closed principle. So, here is how I implemented these changes. Notice how I added a virtual function `SanitizeFieldId` in `ConditionBuilder` and `DateGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder`.

```
public abstract class ConditionBuilder<TContext> : IConditionBuilder where TContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    public abstract string OperatorSymbol { get; }

    public string BuildCondition(SearchCondition searchCondition)
    {
        var conditionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var context = searchCondition.GetContext<TContext>();

        conditionBuilder.Append(SanitizeFieldId(context.FieldId));
        conditionBuilder.Append(OperatorSymbol);
        conditionBuilder.Append(GetValue(context));

        return conditionBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public abstract bool CanHandle(FilterAction filterAction);

    public abstract object GetValue(TContext context);

    protected virtual string SanitizeFieldId(string fieldId)
    {
        return fieldId;
    }
}

public class DateGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder : IConditionBuilder
{
    public const string GREATER_THAN = " > ";

    public const string LESS_THAN_EQUAL = " <= ";

    public string BuildCondition(SearchCondition filterCondition)
    {
        var conditionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var context = filterCondition.GetContext<DateContext>();

        conditionBuilder.Append(SanitizeFieldId(context.FieldId));
        conditionBuilder.Append(GREATER_THAN);
        conditionBuilder.Append("'" + context.FromDate + "'");
        conditionBuilder.Append(LESS_THAN_EQUAL);
        conditionBuilder.Append("'" + context.EndDate + "'");
        return conditionBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.DateGreaterThanLessThan;

    protected virtual string SanitizeFieldId(string fieldId)
    {
        return fieldId;
    }
}

public class SanitizedFieldConditionBuiler<TContext> : ConditionBuilder<TContext> where TContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    private ConditionBuilder<TContext> _baseConditionBuilder;
    private IColumnSanitizer _columnSanitizer;

    public SanitizedFieldConditionBuiler(ConditionBuilder<TContext> baseConditionBuilder, IColumnSanitizer columnSanitizer)
    {
        _baseConditionBuilder = baseConditionBuilder;
        _columnSanitizer = columnSanitizer;
    }

    public override string OperatorSymbol => _baseConditionBuilder.OperatorSymbol;

    public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction filterAction) => _baseConditionBuilder.CanHandle(filterAction);

    public override object GetValue(TContext context) => _baseConditionBuilder.GetValue(context);

    protected override string SanitizeFieldId(string fieldId)
    {
        return _columnSanitizer.Sanitize(fieldId);
    }
}

public class SanitizedDateFieldGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder : DateGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder
{
    private IColumnSanitizer _columnSanitizer;

    public SanitizedDateFieldGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder(IColumnSanitizer columnSanitizer)
    {
        _columnSanitizer = columnSanitizer;
    }

    protected override string SanitizeFieldId(string fieldId)
    {
        return _columnSanitizer.Sanitize(fieldId);
    }
}
```

I use extension methods to initialize `SanitizedFieldConditionBuiler`and `SanitizedDateFieldGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder`as shown below:

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static SanitizedFieldConditionBuiler<TContext> SanitizeField<TContext>(this ConditionBuilder<TContext> source, IColumnSanitizer columnSanitizer) where TContext : FieldSearchContext
        {
            return new SanitizedFieldConditionBuiler<TContext>(source, columnSanitizer);
        }

        public static SanitizedDateFieldGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder SanitizeField(this IConditionBuilder source, IColumnSanitizer columnSanitizer)
        {
            return new SanitizedDateFieldGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder(columnSanitizer);
        }

    }
```

The Sanitization is available by means of an interface `IColumnSanitizer` and has two different implementations, for Sql Server and Oracle respectively

```
 public interface IColumnSanitizer
    {
        string Sanitize(string columnName);
    }

    public class SqlSanitizer : IColumnSanitizer
    {
        public string Sanitize(string columnName)
        {
            return "[" + columnName + "]";
        }
    }

    public class OracleSanitizer : IColumnSanitizer
    {
        public string Sanitize(string columnName)
        {
            return "\"" + columnName + "\"";
        }
    }
```

Below is how context classes are implemented:

```
public abstract class FieldSearchContext
{
    public virtual string FieldId { get; }

    protected FieldSearchContext(string fieldId)
    {
        FieldId = fieldId;
    }
}

public class DateContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    public DateContext(string fieldId, DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? endDate) : base(fieldId)
    {
        FromDate = fromDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public DateTime? FromDate { get; }

    public DateTime? EndDate { get; }
}

public class TextContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    public TextContext(string fieldId, string text) : base(fieldId)
    {
        Text = text;
    }

    public string Text { get; }
}

public class NumericContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    public NumericContext(string fieldId, decimal number) : base(fieldId)
    {
        Number = number;
    }

    public decimal Number { get; }
}
```

These changes work perfectly fine but I want to find out if this can be achieved in a different and better way.

Use the code below to see it in action:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conditions = new List<SearchCondition>()
            {
                new SearchCondition(new NumericContext("Numeric Field", 1234), FilterAction.NumericLessThan),
                new SearchCondition(new TextContext("Text Field", "ASDF"), FilterAction.TextEqual),
                new SearchCondition(new TextContext("Text Field", "QWERTY"), FilterAction.TextLike),
                new SearchCondition(new DateContext("Date Field", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)), FilterAction.DateGreaterThanLessThan)
            };

            Console.WriteLine(BuildWhereClause(Operation.AND, conditions));
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static string BuildWhereClause(Operation operation, IList<SearchCondition> conditions)
        {
            var returnValue = new List<string>();
            var conditionBuilders = new List<IConditionBuilder>()
            {
                new TextEqualsConditionBuilder().SanitizeField(new SqlSanitizer()),
                new NumericLessThanConditionBuilder().SanitizeField(new SqlSanitizer()),
                new TextLikeConditionBuilder().SanitizeField(new SqlSanitizer()),
                new DateGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder().SanitizeField(new SqlSanitizer())
            };

            foreach (var condition in conditions)
            {
                var context = condition.GetContext<FieldSearchContext>();
                var conditionBuilder = conditionBuilders.FirstOrDefault(u => u.CanHandle(condition.FilterAction));
                returnValue.Add(conditionBuilder.BuildCondition(condition));
            }

            if (returnValue.Any())
                return string.Join(Convert.ToString(" " + operation + " "), returnValue);

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    enum Operation : int
    {
        AND = 1,
        OR = 2
    }
```

EDIT:

Added SearchCondition

```
public class SearchCondition
    {
        private readonly FieldSearchContext _fieldSearchContext;

        private FilterAction _filterAction;

        public FilterAction FilterAction
        {
            get { return _filterAction; }
        }

        public SearchCondition(FieldSearchContext fieldSearchContext, FilterAction action)
        {
            _fieldSearchContext = fieldSearchContext;
            _filterAction = action;
        }

        public T GetContext<T>() where T : FieldSearchContext
        {
            return (T)_fieldSearchContext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the implementation of `SearchCondition`?

Comment: @HenrikHansen just added SearchCondition also.

Comment: Post titles should reflect the purpose of the code - I would suggest "SQL Injection Framework" ;-)

Comment: Would be nice to see the definition for `FilterAction`

Comment: And the code snippets are a PITA to copy-paste in an IDE because of your incremental changes.

Comment: Please don't edit the original post in response to existing answers, it invalidates them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP confirmed in a comment that some parts of it aren't real and were edited.

Comment: @t3chb0t they were edited because it was not possible to put all of it here. I added 4 of them here `TextEqualsConditionBuilder`, `NumericLessThanConditionBuilder`, `TextLikeConditionBuilder`, and `DateGreaterThanAndLessThanEqualConditionBuilder` so that I can explain my question clearly. Also it allowed me to put a working copy of the code here which would not have been possible otherwise. If you are saying codereview.stackexchange.com is not meant for such situations then that's fine, but I think that is not right.

Comment: It's always nice when the code can be run but it's optional. More important is that the code is unchanged becuase otherwise reviewing it ends in _The other things you mentioned regarding return "'" + context.Text + "'";, I don't have it that way in the actual code._ which is counterproductive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Sanitizer` is a dangerous misnommer IMO. A better name could be `NameQuoter`, since that's what it does: it uses the RDBMS-specific syntax for *quoting* identifiers - SQL Server using square brackets, MySQL using backticks, Oracle using backslashes: this has nothing to do with *sanitizing*, which from what I can tell is essentially impossible to achieve with this framework that I would dub "SQL Injection Framework".

`FieldId` is also a misnommer - I don't know about Oracle, but on SQL Server every database object has an ID, and I would read "field ID" as a value that's referring to that ID. What you have is a `ColumnName`, not an ID.

`Context` is also a confusing name: in Entity Framework, `Context` refers to the unit of work; it encapsulates a transaction and exposes the repositories - as far as client code is concernd, it *is* the database connection... anyone remotely familiar with standard .NET data access code will raise an eyebrow at "context" being used to refer to what's essentially a wrapper object for various types of values. Why can't a `decimal` be `null`, but a `DateTime` can?

This is a problem:

```
public abstract class FieldSearchContext
{
    public virtual string FieldId { get; }

    protected FieldSearchContext(string fieldId)
    {
        FieldId = fieldId;
    }
}
```

You're assigning a `virtual` property in the base constructor. That property should not be `virtual` at all. Here's why it's a problem:

```
public class BrokenSearchContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    public BrokenSearchContext() : base("Foo") { }

    public override string FieldId => "Bar";
}
```

The base constructor runs first, receives `"Foo"`, invokes the `FieldId` property... which is overridden in the derived class... as an immutable getter. How is the base class assigning its `FieldId` now? Right: it doesn't... and that merely makes things confusing *in this case* (value read isn't the value written) - but in other situations it could mean a bug that's very hard to track down.

Avoid `virtual` member calls in a constructors - might be innocuous in this particular case, but one day you'll be invoking a side-effecting virtual method in a base constructor, and you're not going to like it. `FieldId` has no reason to be `virtual` in the first place.

But of all problems, this is the single most dangerous one:

```
public override object GetValue(TextContext context)
{
    if (context.Text == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return "'" + context.Text + "'";
}
```

See, I like Irish whiskey, and code like this makes me want to order a double. What happens when `context.Text` is `Elizabeth O'Connor`? Or `Patrick O'Neil`?

Or [`Robert';DROP TABLE Students;--`](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

I'm sorry to say, the most pressing issue with this code isn't how bloated this whole "criteria builder" tooling works, nor how well it does or doesn't adhere to OCP: the most pressing issue with this code is that it's literally a *SQL Injection Framework*, making it child's play to generate SQL statements that can - and if this goes anywhere near a public-facing client, eventually *will* - contain malicious data... all while the consuming C# code looks and reads very much like it's perfectly safe & secure.

The biggest problem with this code, is that *it exists* - concatenating parameter values into SQL statements **is not the job of the client connection**. It's the job of the server, and doing this in a secure way involves commands and parameters - not string concatenations.

I wouldn't worry about breaking existing code - the existing code *is already broken*, beyond repair.

To be clear: the solution isn't to escape single quotes or make sure SQL keywords aren't present in the string - the solution is to stop concatenating WHERE clauses in SQL strings.

Consider using an ORM, e.g. Entity Framework - or Dapper.NET if you want a lightweight but performant solution, to generate properly parameterized SQL statements without any concatenation.

Comment: This review clears the queue of potential other reviewers. At least for me, I'm out :) On to the next question for me..

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, Thank you for your review, I appreciate your feedback. I liked the suggestion of changing the name from Sanitizer to NameQuoter. Also that line `public virtual string FieldId { get; }` was placed mistakenly, I was trying a few things in a small sample and forgot to remove it before I posted here . I don't have it in the actual application. The other things you mentioned regarding `return "'" + context.Text + "'";`, I don't have it that way in the actual code. Thanks again.

Comment: @AashishUpadhyay see, this is exactly why we **require** that you submit your real, actual, working code for peer review. For the record, there is no secure way to concatenate WHERE clause values into a SQL string. Do not do this. I don't know what your "actual code" is actually doing, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't involve commands and parameters, otherwise you wouldn't have written any of this.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Noted.  Yes it doesn't take care of parameters and I don't think it can be changed also.

Comment: *I don't think it can be changed* - read up on the [Sunk Cost Fallacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost) - string-concatenating WHERE clauses is a plague that needs to be eradicated with all the firepower you can throw at it. It will cost more in the long run to keep doing that, than rewriting everything to implement data access code *properly*, and that's been proven many times over - just ask any company victim of a data breach. String-concatenating WHERE clauses is a *very* serious security issue.

Comment: _string-concatenating WHERE clauses is a plague that needs to be eradicated_ - sure, only how? Have you seen any resonable and working solution to this problem? I myslef do this in a couple of places because neither EF nor Dapper are better than doing this manually yourself. In fact, none of the ORMs can deal with any danymic SQL so you always have to fallback to ordinary string concatenation and if you need anything more fancy than this is your only option. I find string-concating WHERE is as dangerous as anything else in coding so there is no reason to panic ;-]

Comment: I'd even say that doing this is like building file paths. One bad move and you've deleted/overwritten an import directory and nobody is trying to avoid dynamic paths, or anything dynamic that no matter what you do, it can always go sideways.

Comment: @t3chb0t map each "dynamic field name + value" to an object that gives you a `@namedParameter` with its value, and assuming the field names aren't user inputs then there should be a way to build your dynamic SQL into a parameterized command string that can be safely executed without concatenating any criterion. Heck I bet I could write this in VBA with `?` positional parameters.

Comment: *string-concating WHERE is as dangerous as anything else in coding so there is no reason to panic* - tell that to Mrs.Null and Mr.O'Neil ;-)

Comment: Not buying it ;-] I'm sure there's been incidents with any API but only because people used them irresponsibly like by ignoring edge cases etc.

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm not making this up. http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems

Comment: @t3chb0t your file path analogy falls apart because you don't have outsiders providing parts of the file path, giving them an opportunity to be malicious. With concatenated `WHERE` clauses that take end user input, I can [_intentionally_](https://xkcd.com/327/) add SQL statements that weren't anticipated by the developer and cause major damage.

Comment: @FreeMan _your file path analogy falls apart_ - does it? I could build a web-service allowing users to upload files and do all kinds of freaky directory and file manipulation stuff... I can let them upload json that I deserialize without validating types... I can let them call .net framework functions for some calculator etc without validating whether they are allowed... everything is dangerous when done the wrong way or simply carelessly.

Comment: @t3chb0t except some dangerous things are very niche, and others extremely widespread. Directory manipulation through JSON deserialization is one, glaring SQL injection vulnerabilities are the other.

Comment: @t3chb0t I guess my point is, in the spirit of "making wrong code look wrong", if you're going to have dynamic-SQL with string-concatenated parameters, don't make it look like a sophisticated SQL-generator engine. If you're going to concatenate SQL WHERE clauses, *just concatenate SQL WHERE clauses* - that way it's wrong, *and it looks that way*. The problem I have with something like what the OP has built is that it's hiding the vulnerability behind 20 layers of abstraction, using terminology that makes it *look* like the consuming code might be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

Just one thing...

#### Use db-provider's *sanitizer*

There is already a *sanitizer* that the `DbCommandBuilder` provides. You can use it like this:

```
using (var commandBuilder = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(sqlConnection).CreateCommandBuilder())
{
    return commandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(name);
}
```

I'm pretty sure the `Oracle` provider has it too (when you install its NuGet package). You should use these instead of inventing your own.